# OutofMemory exception in the application

Tags: c#

in the application log files this is the error we are getting

> 2012-07-19 15:08:46,995 [17] WARN  System.Web.UI.Page [(null)] -
>   Logging:System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.    at
>   System.String.GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32
>   startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)    at
>   System.Text.StringBuilder.GetNewString(String currentString, Int32
>   requiredLength)    at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(String value)

can any one suggest how to avoid this problem. we have used string builder for writing the data into the excel sheet

here is the code

```
public void ToCSV(DataTable dt)
{
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    try
    {

        sb = new StringBuilder(50*1024);
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            sb.Append(col.ColumnName + ",");
        }
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append("\"" + row[i].ToString() + "\"" + ",");
            }
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Session["exportsCsv"] = sb;
        sb = null;


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        log.Warn("Logging:" + ex);

    }
    finally {
        sb = null;

    }
    //
```

Comment: Post the relevant code, please.

Comment: We cannot advice anything if you don't give us some additional information like PC type (embedded, server, personal) and some code where the exception was thrown

Comment: Well seeing the code that logs would help...

Comment: btw you don't have to set sb to null explicitly, it will go out of scope after the method will finish.

Comment: The error means that you have exhausted available memory. Do you need additional information?

Comment: Yes i need additional information

Answer (score 0):

```
sb.Append("\"" + row[i].ToString() + "\"" + ",");
```

===>

```
sb.Append('\"').Append(row[i].ToString()).Append("\",");
```

Try not to generate the whole csv file in one StringBuilder, write to a stream instead.

Answer (score 0):

How much data are you adding to the CSV file?  The `String` and `StringBuilder` classes are limited to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647) characters, which could be restricted further by your computer's memory.

To write large amounts of data to a file or network client, write it to a `Stream` instead.

```
public void ToCSV(DataTable dt, Stream outStream)
{ 
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outStream); 
    try 
    { 
        bool first = true;
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) 
        {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                writer.Write(",");

            writer.Write(col.ColumnName); 
        } 
        writer.WriteLine(); 
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) 
            { 
                writer.Write("\"" + row[i].ToString() + "\"" + ","); 
            } 
            writer.WriteLine(); 
        } 
        // Not sure what to replace this with:
        //Session["exportsCsv"] = sb; 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); 
        log.Warn("Logging:" + ex); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: sorry one more question what should i have to pass for the stream outstream variable from the calling function

Comment: That depends on what you're doing.  What is your `Session["exportsCsv"]` related to?  I'm guessing it's to do with ASP pages, which I have little experience with.

Comment: session["exportscsv"] used to store the string builder thats where we have stored the entire data we got from the database. so that we can use it some other location in the application.